# Speed up reading wav in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, wav

Evening,

I am working on a project that requires me to read in multichannel wav files in 32-bit float.
When I read a specific file (1 minute long, 6 channels, 48k fs) in into Matlab and measure it with tic/toc it parses the file in 2.456482 seconds.

Matlab Code for file reading speed measurement
    tic
    wavread('C:/data/testData/6ch.wav');
    toc

When I do it in python (mind you, I'm pretty unfamiliar with python) it takes 18.1655315617 seconds!
It seems to me like the way I am doing it is inefficient (I did get it down to 18 from 28 but it's still too much...)

I stripped the code to what is relevant to this subject:

Python Code for file reading speed measurement

```
import wave32
import struct
import time
import numpy as np

def getWavData(inFile)
    wavFile = wave32.open(inFile, 'r')
    wavParams = wavFile.getparams()
    nChannels = wavParams[0]
    byteDepth = wavParams[1]
    nFrames = wavParams[3]
    wavData = np.empty([nFrames, nChannels], np.float32)
    frames = wavFile.readframes(nFrames) 
    for i in range(nFrames):
        for j in range(nChannels):
            start = ( i * nChannels + j ) * byteDepth
            stop = start + byteDepth
            wavData[i][j] = struct.unpack('<f', frames[start:stop])[0]
    return wavData

inFile = 'C:/data/testData/6ch.wav'
start = time.clock() 
data2 = getWavData(inFile)
elapsed = time.clock()
elapsedNew = elapsed - start
print str(elapsedNew)
```

please not that wav32 is a small hack I had to perform on wave.py to enable 32-bit float reading.

```
"""Stuff to parse WAVE files.

Usage.

Reading WAVE files:
      f = wave.open(file, 'r')
where file is either the name of a file or an open file pointer.
The open file pointer must have methods read(), seek(), and close().
When the setpos() and rewind() methods are not used, the seek()
method is not  necessary.

This returns an instance of a class with the following public methods:
      getnchannels()  -- returns number of audio channels (1 for
                         mono, 2 for stereo)
      getsampwidth()  -- returns sample width in bytes
      getframerate()  -- returns sampling frequency
      getnframes()    -- returns number of audio frames
      getcomptype()   -- returns compression type ('NONE' for linear samples)
      getcompname()   -- returns human-readable version of
                         compression type ('not compressed' linear samples)
      getparams()     -- returns a tuple consisting of all of the
                         above in the above order
      getmarkers()    -- returns None (for compatibility with the
                         aifc module)
      getmark(id)     -- raises an error since the mark does not
                         exist (for compatibility with the aifc module)
      readframes(n)   -- returns at most n frames of audio
      rewind()        -- rewind to the beginning of the audio stream
      setpos(pos)     -- seek to the specified position
      tell()          -- return the current position
      close()         -- close the instance (make it unusable)
The position returned by tell() and the position given to setpos()
are compatible and have nothing to do with the actual position in the
file.
The close() method is called automatically when the class instance
is destroyed.

Writing WAVE files:
      f = wave.open(file, 'w')
where file is either the name of a file or an open file pointer.
The open file pointer must have methods write(), tell(), seek(), and
close().

This returns an instance of a class with the following public methods:
      setnchannels(n) -- set the number of channels
      setsampwidth(n) -- set the sample width
      setframerate(n) -- set the frame rate
      setnframes(n)   -- set the number of frames
      setcomptype(type, name)
                      -- set the compression type and the
                         human-readable compression type
      setparams(tuple)
                      -- set all parameters at once
      tell()          -- return current position in output file
      writeframesraw(data)
                      -- write audio frames without pathing up the
                         file header
      writeframes(data)
                      -- write audio frames and patch up the file header
      close()         -- patch up the file header and close the
                         output file
You should set the parameters before the first writeframesraw or
writeframes.  The total number of frames does not need to be set,
but when it is set to the correct value, the header does not have to
be patched up.
It is best to first set all parameters, perhaps possibly the
compression type, and then write audio frames using writeframesraw.
When all frames have been written, either call writeframes('') or
close() to patch up the sizes in the header.
The close() method is called automatically when the class instance
is destroyed.
"""

import __builtin__

__all__ = ["open", "openfp", "Error"]

class Error(Exception):
    pass

WAVE_FORMAT_PCM = 0x0001
WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT = 0x0003

_array_fmts = None, 'b', 'h', None, 'l'

# Determine endian-ness
import struct
if struct.pack("h", 1) == "\000\001":
    big_endian = 1
else:
    big_endian = 0

from chunk import Chunk

class Wave_read:
    """Variables used in this class:

    These variables are available to the user though appropriate
    methods of this class:
    _file -- the open file with methods read(), close(), and seek()
              set through the __init__() method
    _nchannels -- the number of audio channels
              available through the getnchannels() method
    _nframes -- the number of audio frames
              available through the getnframes() method
    _sampwidth -- the number of bytes per audio sample
              available through the getsampwidth() method
    _framerate -- the sampling frequency
              available through the getframerate() method
    _comptype -- the AIFF-C compression type ('NONE' if AIFF)
              available through the getcomptype() method
    _compname -- the human-readable AIFF-C compression type
              available through the getcomptype() method
    _soundpos -- the position in the audio stream
              available through the tell() method, set through the
              setpos() method

    These variables are used internally only:
    _fmt_chunk_read -- 1 iff the FMT chunk has been read
    _data_seek_needed -- 1 iff positioned correctly in audio
              file for readframes()
    _data_chunk -- instantiation of a chunk class for the DATA chunk
    _framesize -- size of one frame in the file
    """

    def initfp(self, file):
        self._convert = None
        self._soundpos = 0
        self._file = Chunk(file, bigendian = 0)
        if self._file.getname() != 'RIFF':
            raise Error, 'file does not start with RIFF id'
        if self._file.read(4) != 'WAVE':
            raise Error, 'not a WAVE file'
        self._fmt_chunk_read = 0
        self._data_chunk = None
        while 1:
            self._data_seek_needed = 1
            try:
                chunk = Chunk(self._file, bigendian = 0)
            except EOFError:
                break
            chunkname = chunk.getname()
            if chunkname == 'fmt ':
                self._read_fmt_chunk(chunk)
                self._fmt_chunk_read = 1
            elif chunkname == 'data':
                if not self._fmt_chunk_read:
                    raise Error, 'data chunk before fmt chunk'
                self._data_chunk = chunk
                self._nframes = chunk.chunksize // self._framesize
                self._data_seek_needed = 0
                break
            chunk.skip()
        if not self._fmt_chunk_read or not self._data_chunk:
            raise Error, 'fmt chunk and/or data chunk missing'

    def __init__(self, f):
        self._i_opened_the_file = None
        if isinstance(f, basestring):
            f = __builtin__.open(f, 'rb')
            self._i_opened_the_file = f
        # else, assume it is an open file object already
        try:
            self.initfp(f)
        except:
            if self._i_opened_the_file:
                f.close()
            raise

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()
    #
    # User visible methods.
    #
    def getfp(self):
        return self._file

    def rewind(self):
        self._data_seek_needed = 1
        self._soundpos = 0

    def close(self):
        if self._i_opened_the_file:
            self._i_opened_the_file.close()
            self._i_opened_the_file = None
        self._file = None

    def tell(self):
        return self._soundpos

    def getnchannels(self):
        return self._nchannels

    def getnframes(self):
        return self._nframes

    def getsampwidth(self):
        return self._sampwidth

    def getframerate(self):
        return self._framerate

    def getcomptype(self):
        return self._comptype

    def getcompname(self):
        return self._compname

    def getparams(self):
        return self.getnchannels(), self.getsampwidth(), \
               self.getframerate(), self.getnframes(), \
               self.getcomptype(), self.getcompname()

    def getmarkers(self):
        return None

    def getmark(self, id):
        raise Error, 'no marks'

    def setpos(self, pos):
        if pos < 0 or pos > self._nframes:
            raise Error, 'position not in range'
        self._soundpos = pos
        self._data_seek_needed = 1

    def readframes(self, nframes):
        if self._data_seek_needed:
            self._data_chunk.seek(0, 0)
            pos = self._soundpos * self._framesize
            if pos:
                self._data_chunk.seek(pos, 0)
            self._data_seek_needed = 0
        if nframes == 0:
            return ''
        if self._sampwidth > 1 and big_endian:
            # unfortunately the fromfile() method does not take
            # something that only looks like a file object, so
            # we have to reach into the innards of the chunk object
            import array
            chunk = self._data_chunk
            data = array.array(_array_fmts[self._sampwidth])
            nitems = nframes * self._nchannels
            if nitems * self._sampwidth > chunk.chunksize - chunk.size_read:
                nitems = (chunk.chunksize - chunk.size_read) / self._sampwidth
            data.fromfile(chunk.file.file, nitems)
            # "tell" data chunk how much was read
            chunk.size_read = chunk.size_read + nitems * self._sampwidth
            # do the same for the outermost chunk
            chunk = chunk.file
            chunk.size_read = chunk.size_read + nitems * self._sampwidth
            data.byteswap()
            data = data.tostring()
        else:
            data = self._data_chunk.read(nframes * self._framesize)
        if self._convert and data:
            data = self._convert(data)
        self._soundpos = self._soundpos + len(data) // (self._nchannels * self._sampwidth)
        return data

    #
    # Internal methods.
    #
    def _read_fmt_chunk(self, chunk):
        wFormatTag, self._nchannels, self._framerate, dwAvgBytesPerSec, wBlockAlign = struct.unpack('<hhllh', chunk.read(14))
        if wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_PCM or wFormatTag==WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT:
            sampwidth = struct.unpack('<h', chunk.read(2))[0]
            self._sampwidth = (sampwidth + 7) // 8
        else:
            #sampwidth = struct.unpack('<h', chunk.read(2))[0]
            #self._sampwidth = (sampwidth + 7) // 8
            raise Error, 'unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,)
        self._framesize = self._nchannels * self._sampwidth
        self._comptype = 'NONE'
        self._compname = 'not compressed'

class Wave_write:
    """Variables used in this class:

    These variables are user settable through appropriate methods
    of this class:
    _file -- the open file with methods write(), close(), tell(), seek()
              set through the __init__() method
    _comptype -- the AIFF-C compression type ('NONE' in AIFF)
              set through the setcomptype() or setparams() method
    _compname -- the human-readable AIFF-C compression type
              set through the setcomptype() or setparams() method
    _nchannels -- the number of audio channels
              set through the setnchannels() or setparams() method
    _sampwidth -- the number of bytes per audio sample
              set through the setsampwidth() or setparams() method
    _framerate -- the sampling frequency
              set through the setframerate() or setparams() method
    _nframes -- the number of audio frames written to the header
              set through the setnframes() or setparams() method

    These variables are used internally only:
    _datalength -- the size of the audio samples written to the header
    _nframeswritten -- the number of frames actually written
    _datawritten -- the size of the audio samples actually written
    """

    def __init__(self, f):
        self._i_opened_the_file = None
        if isinstance(f, basestring):
            f = __builtin__.open(f, 'wb')
            self._i_opened_the_file = f
        try:
            self.initfp(f)
        except:
            if self._i_opened_the_file:
                f.close()
            raise

    def initfp(self, file):
        self._file = file
        self._convert = None
        self._nchannels = 0
        self._sampwidth = 0
        self._framerate = 0
        self._nframes = 0
        self._nframeswritten = 0
        self._datawritten = 0
        self._datalength = 0
        self._headerwritten = False

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

    #
    # User visible methods.
    #
    def setnchannels(self, nchannels):
        if self._datawritten:
            raise Error, 'cannot change parameters after starting to write'
        if nchannels < 1:
            raise Error, 'bad # of channels'
        self._nchannels = nchannels

    def getnchannels(self):
        if not self._nchannels:
            raise Error, 'number of channels not set'
        return self._nchannels

    def setsampwidth(self, sampwidth):
        if self._datawritten:
            raise Error, 'cannot change parameters after starting to write'
        if sampwidth < 1 or sampwidth > 4:
            raise Error, 'bad sample width'
        self._sampwidth = sampwidth

    def getsampwidth(self):
        if not self._sampwidth:
            raise Error, 'sample width not set'
        return self._sampwidth

    def setframerate(self, framerate):
        if self._datawritten:
            raise Error, 'cannot change parameters after starting to write'
        if framerate <= 0:
            raise Error, 'bad frame rate'
        self._framerate = framerate

    def getframerate(self):
        if not self._framerate:
            raise Error, 'frame rate not set'
        return self._framerate

    def setnframes(self, nframes):
        if self._datawritten:
            raise Error, 'cannot change parameters after starting to write'
        self._nframes = nframes

    def getnframes(self):
        return self._nframeswritten

    def setcomptype(self, comptype, compname):
        if self._datawritten:
            raise Error, 'cannot change parameters after starting to write'
        if comptype not in ('NONE',):
            raise Error, 'unsupported compression type'
        self._comptype = comptype
        self._compname = compname

    def getcomptype(self):
        return self._comptype

    def getcompname(self):
        return self._compname

    def setparams(self, params):
        nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname = params
        if self._datawritten:
            raise Error, 'cannot change parameters after starting to write'
        self.setnchannels(nchannels)
        self.setsampwidth(sampwidth)
        self.setframerate(framerate)
        self.setnframes(nframes)
        self.setcomptype(comptype, compname)

    def getparams(self):
        if not self._nchannels or not self._sampwidth or not self._framerate:
            raise Error, 'not all parameters set'
        return self._nchannels, self._sampwidth, self._framerate, \
              self._nframes, self._comptype, self._compname

    def setmark(self, id, pos, name):
        raise Error, 'setmark() not supported'

    def getmark(self, id):
        raise Error, 'no marks'

    def getmarkers(self):
        return None

    def tell(self):
        return self._nframeswritten

    def writeframesraw(self, data):
        self._ensure_header_written(len(data))
        nframes = len(data) // (self._sampwidth * self._nchannels)
        if self._convert:
            data = self._convert(data)
        if self._sampwidth > 1 and big_endian:
            import array
            data = array.array(_array_fmts[self._sampwidth], data)
            data.byteswap()
            data.tofile(self._file)
            self._datawritten = self._datawritten + len(data) * self._sampwidth
        else:
            self._file.write(data)
            self._datawritten = self._datawritten + len(data)
        self._nframeswritten = self._nframeswritten + nframes

    def writeframes(self, data):
        self.writeframesraw(data)
        if self._datalength != self._datawritten:
            self._patchheader()

    def close(self):
        if self._file:
            self._ensure_header_written(0)
            if self._datalength != self._datawritten:
                self._patchheader()
            self._file.flush()
            self._file = None
        if self._i_opened_the_file:
            self._i_opened_the_file.close()
            self._i_opened_the_file = None

    #
    # Internal methods.
    #

    def _ensure_header_written(self, datasize):
        if not self._headerwritten:
            if not self._nchannels:
                raise Error, '# channels not specified'
            if not self._sampwidth:
                raise Error, 'sample width not specified'
            if not self._framerate:
                raise Error, 'sampling rate not specified'
            self._write_header(datasize)

    def _write_header(self, initlength):
        assert not self._headerwritten
        self._file.write('RIFF')
        if not self._nframes:
            self._nframes = initlength / (self._nchannels * self._sampwidth)
        self._datalength = self._nframes * self._nchannels * self._sampwidth
        self._form_length_pos = self._file.tell()
        self._file.write(struct.pack('<l4s4slhhllhh4s',
            36 + self._datalength, 'WAVE', 'fmt ', 16,
            WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, self._nchannels, self._framerate,
            self._nchannels * self._framerate * self._sampwidth,
            self._nchannels * self._sampwidth,
            self._sampwidth * 8, 'data'))
        self._data_length_pos = self._file.tell()
        self._file.write(struct.pack('<l', self._datalength))
        self._headerwritten = True

    def _patchheader(self):
        assert self._headerwritten
        if self._datawritten == self._datalength:
            return
        curpos = self._file.tell()
        self._file.seek(self._form_length_pos, 0)
        self._file.write(struct.pack('<l', 36 + self._datawritten))
        self._file.seek(self._data_length_pos, 0)
        self._file.write(struct.pack('<l', self._datawritten))
        self._file.seek(curpos, 0)
        self._datalength = self._datawritten

def open(f, mode=None):
    if mode is None:
        if hasattr(f, 'mode'):
            mode = f.mode
        else:
            mode = 'rb'
    if mode in ('r', 'rb'):
        return Wave_read(f)
    elif mode in ('w', 'wb'):
        return Wave_write(f)
    else:
        raise Error, "mode must be 'r', 'rb', 'w', or 'wb'"

openfp = open # B/W compatibility
```

Sorry for the long code BTW :)

---

So my question is: is the wave.py module inherently slow (any alternatives to fix this?) or am I doing something inefficient?

I suppose I could just read in the wav header with a custom function and read the file in in a different way, but it seems like this is going to be A LOT of work, especially since I don't know a lot about 1) python and 2) file handling

Kind regards,

K.

---

Edit: I tried unutbu's suggestion but that does not work as scipy does not accept >16 bit.

When I try to parse the wav file through the scipy wavreader I get this message:

```
C:\Users\King Broos\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\System\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py:31: WavFileWarning: Unfamiliar format bytes
  warnings.warn("Unfamiliar format bytes", WavFileWarning)

C:\Users\King Broos\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\System\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py:121: WavFileWarning: chunk not understood
  warnings.warn("chunk not understood", WavFileWarning)
```

Looking into the code of wavfile.py this is the line where it throws the exception:

```
    if (comp != 1 or size > 16):
    warnings.warn("Unfamiliar format bytes", WavFileWarning)
```

I really need either 24 or 32 bit so I guess scipy not an option?

Comment: The errors you think you are getting from `scipy.io.wavfile` are only warnings: it doesn't know what it is doing, but it does it any way. So you may need to do some extra work, but if you know what you are doing you should be able to make things work: I just read a 64-bit float WAV file from [here](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples.html) using `rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename)`, and the only caveat is that `data` is of type `np.int64`. If you view that same data as 64 bit floats, i.e. `data = data.view(np.float64)`, you should get the right format.

Answer (score 2):

If you can install or have [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/index.html), then use [wavfile.read](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html):

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
sample_rate, x = wavfile.read(filename)
```

You might also want to study the [source code, here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.12.0/scipy/io/wavfile.py#L97).

---

Note that `scipy.io.wavfile` does not use Python's `wave` module. I'm not sure if it reads your IEEE_FLOAT format or not, but it does not do the same check as `wave.py`:

```
    if wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_PCM or wFormatTag==WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT:
        sampwidth = struct.unpack('<h', chunk.read(2))[0]
        self._sampwidth = (sampwidth + 7) // 8
    else:
        #sampwidth = struct.unpack('<h', chunk.read(2))[0]
        #self._sampwidth = (sampwidth + 7) // 8
        raise Error, 'unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,)
```

so perhaps it will work out-of-the-box.

---

By the way, instead of making your own module, `wave32.py` which is almost exactly the same as `wave.py` from the standard library, you could use monkey-patching:

```
import wave
import struct

WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT = 0x0003
def _read_fmt_chunk(self, chunk):
    wFormatTag, self._nchannels, self._framerate, dwAvgBytesPerSec, wBlockAlign = struct.unpack('<hhllh', chunk.read(14))
    if wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_PCM or wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT:
        sampwidth = struct.unpack('<h', chunk.read(2))[0]
        self._sampwidth = (sampwidth + 7) // 8
    else:
        raise Error, 'unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,)
    self._framesize = self._nchannels * self._sampwidth
    self._comptype = 'NONE'
    self._compname = 'not compressed'

wave.Wave_read._read_fmt_chunk = _read_fmt_chunk
```

Comment: Installing scipy as a dependency is not an issue. The issue with reading wav with scipy is that it does not support >16 bit audio, which is unacceptable for the work I'm doing, as I'm evaluating the lowest order bits of a 24-bit audio codec.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use numpy directly:

```
import numpy as np
fs = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.int32, count=1, offset=24)[0] # Hz
byte_length = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.int32, count=1, offset=40)[0]
```

To manually read pieces of metadata. I recommend using a hex editor and wave format reference to verify the locations for pieces of metadata and the `offset` to the start of the data chunk (might not be 40 or 44 bytes in).

To read 32-bit WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT:

```
data = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.float32, count=byte_length // 4, offset=44)
```

To read 24-bit WAVE_FORMAT_PCM:

```
# prepend zero-byte to each sample (since there's no np.int24) 
# then flatten, convert normally and byte-shift to correct for extra byte
data = np.zeros([byte_length // 3, 4], dtype=np.int8)
data[:, 1:] = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.int8, count=byte_length, offset=44).reshape(-1, 3)
data = np.right_shift(data.reshape(-1).view(dtype=np.int32), 8)
data = data / 2 ** 23 # if you want to normalize
```

Depends on the wavefile and machine, but this seems to be ~120 times faster than a loop for a 4.4 MB 24-bit .wav file, but there's likely bigger performance gains for bigger files (until swap is required, I think there's ~5 memory copies performed, including normalization).

This assumes:

- No extra chunks at the start of the file, else `offset=` parameters are wrong
- Single channel - reshape the array and/or change the byte order for multi-channel, with something like `.reshape(num_channels, -1, order='F')`
- Little-endian I think